# How to make flow run successfully when updating blank/empty "Date" column from Excel Table to Sharepoint List "Date" column with our error?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, excel-dates

I created an automate flow to convert Excel table to SP List. In Excel Table it includes "Date" column which could be blank/empty. And this has caused flow error when updating "Date" column in SP List. My flow structure as attached [Automate flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVsS1.png)

Comment: Can you share you error message? And can you also share the length expression from the screenshot?

Comment: Thank you, I just solved it yesterday. I change my "Date" expression for SP "Date" column to if(equals(items('Apply_to_each_1')?['DATE'],''),null,addDays('1899-12-30',int(items('Apply_to_each_1')?['DATE']),'MM/dd/yyyy')) , however, if the excel "Date" column mix text type info, then the flows failed, too.  Below was previous error msg.
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Update_item' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type.'.